# SSRS - use case of JOIN, SPLIT, combination of both

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

In SSRS, I am trying to understand the use case of Join and Split.

Lets say we have a multi-value Parameter on the SSRS report.

Assume we also have an embedded SQL or SP that accepts the above parameter (**multi-value parameter** @ParamName):

```
SELECT  id,name
FROM    someTableValuedFunction(@ParamName,',')
```

In order to be able to pass in the parameter value we should use the foll. expr at the dataset param:

```
=Join(Parameters!ParamName.Value,",")
```

This is because the SQL code accepts a single value parameter and Join does exactly that. And similarly the above Join can also be used to display the param value on the report if required.

Or is the JOIN function only needed if we want to display the parameter value on the report? In normal SQL/SP param it sufficient to use `Parameters!ParamName.Value` ?

Also, when do we use the SPLIT function? Example:

```
=Split(Parameters!ParamName.Value,",")
```

Is it that - when the SQL code requires that the parameter value be in form of a table - for example when the SQL is:

```
WHERE ColumnName IN (@Param)
```

What about the use case of:

```
=Split(Join(Parameters!ParamName.Value,","))
```

Comment: Why your are not creating Parameters with "Allow Multiples values" ?

Comment: Yes its a multivalue parameter with "Allow Multiples values" checked!